# time not declared in scope, how do I find which includes a file uses?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, time

This is driving me nuts, I have been stuck on this problem for a few hours.  I'm using time.h in several files in my project, and on every one get the error "time was not declared in scope" when I try to use the function time().  The strange thing is time_t is defined, I get no errors about it.  I thought perhaps it was pulling in the C++ version somehow so tried using namespace std:: but that didn't work either.  struct tm and localtime aren't declared in scope either.  All code compiles fine on other systems BTW.

I'm going nuts here, how can I figure out what headers a file is using, what is defined or what is going on?  I don't know how to proceed, please help!

I am using GCC 4.2 in Xcode 3.2.5 with 10.6 SDK

In case you want to see the code here it is, not useful though, it has to be a compiler/include file problem I think.

```
            time_t long_time;
            time(&long_time);
            tm* st = localtime(&long_time);
            sprintf(temp, "%02d:%02d:%02d %02d.%02d.%04d  ",
                    st->tm_hour, st->tm_min, st->tm_sec, st->tm_mon+1, st->tm_mday, st->tm_year+1900);
```

Comment: You actually have `#include <time.h>` among the first lines of the file which you're trying to use time functions in? Or have you just forgot to do it?

Comment: @H2CO3 Is on the right lines I think; show us your `#include` statements.  To answer your question though, you go to `Terminal` and type `man -s 3 time` or `man -s 3 localtime` and it tells you what needs to be included.

Comment: Try opening up `time.h` in Xcode, File-Open Quickly-time.h  BTW I am able to use `time()` on Mountain Lion Xcode 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. i am using enet which has a header called time.h, because xcode couldn't find the enet files under a sub directory I included it in my User Header Search Paths, apparently the compiler looks in user paths first and was pulling in the enet time.h instead of the system one