# Error Recompiling C++ program on OS X (Undeclared __time_t)

Tags: c++, g++, osx-lion

**OS:** Mac OS X 10.8.4 
**Compiler:** g++ 4.1 
**Utilities:** Downloaded as Xcode Development Tools

I am trying to recompile a .cpp program that was written on some Linux System (not sure which) using g++ 4.1. I am trying to recompile it g++ 4.1 in OS X instead.

The problem is there are some declarations that use type __time_t such as:

```
__time_t lastDataRx;
__time_t lastHealthSent;
__time_t lasterrorsent;
```

which lead to errors like:

```
"error: ‘__time_t’ was not declared in this scope"
```

The included header files are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "accel.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

I would assume __time_t would be defined in `<sys/time.h>` but the resulting errors seem to contradict me.

Similar question but might not apply:
[time not declared in scope, how do I find which includes a file uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720501/time-not-declared-in-scope-how-do-i-find-which-includes-a-file-uses)

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` looks more like C than C++... Anyway, the standard type is [`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) (defined in `<ctime>`/`<time.h>`). Likely `__time_t` was an implementation-specific type on the Linux but doesn't exist on the Mac OS X. I have no idea why the original code used an implementation type directly rather than the standard one, but can't you just replace occurrences of `__time_t` with `time_t`?

Comment: As gx_ said, replace the platform-peculiar `__time_t` with `time_t`.  Nice easy global search and replace.  Names that start with double-underscore should be treated as private to the implementation.  The code is broken on Linux too — it just compiles OK.  The x-ref'd questions is unlikely to be relevant to your problem (check with `gcc -H` if you want to be sure).

Comment: @ gx The main file is a .cpp which references some .c files which is perhaps far from the best practices. 

But at any rate, the issue seems to be solved by using changing the declarations as you guys suggested. I wasn't sure if there was a special reason for having the __time_t but if it is just a different version of standard time then I guess it can't hurt.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is GCC or the GNU C library (the library, I think), but the names such as `__time_t` are internal names used to define the name without the `__`  prefix.  It allows the name to be defined regardless of the compiler options (because it is in the namespace 'reserved for the implementation').